# One word that describes one who does not stand up for oneself

Tags: single-word-requests

Pushover comes to mind. But I need a more attractive sounding word.

Comment: **Chicken, wuss, milksop, weakling and feeble come to mind**

Comment: "Wimp" is the first thing that comes to my mind.  But there are plenty of others.  A lot depends on the tone and "sophistication" you're looking for.  "Spineless" is probably a bit higher toned.

Comment: Do you have a context in which you are planning to use this word?  Can you give us more guidance than just "more attractive-sounding"?

Comment: By *more attractive sounding* do you mean less negative, more formal, or simply more euphonic?

Comment: If you want a term that is reasonably non-prejudicial then "unassertive" or "non-assertive" is probably a better choice.

Comment: +1 @Mauli Davidson, please post your suggestion of "timid" (with some citation) so I can upvote it - so far it is more responsive to OP's request, IMHO, than the others.

Answer (score 1):

A [wimp](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/wimp?s=t) or a *spineless person*:

> - a weak, ineffectual, timid person.

also a [defeatist](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/defeatist?s=ts):

> - someone who is resigned to defeat without offering positive suggestions

(TFD)

Comment: How about, "**timid**".

Comment: @MauliDavidson - Nah, too timid.

Answer (score 1):

It is not a single word, but it is more attractive:

*[Soft touch](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/soft-touch-also-easy-touch?q=soft%20touch)*

> informal A person who readily gives or does something if asked.